# Lazily load data in jquery DataTable as per the request

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, datatable

I am using `jquery DataTables` to populate tables. We can get huge size of data and render it on html and put pagination/search etc using `DataTable`. I haven't used it earlier but I assume that it will die sometimes (after a limit). And anyways, bringing whole data in one go might not help in future.

Is there any way to make ajax calls when user reaches the last page of DataTable and fetch remaining data?

I hope, I am clear. Any alternative to perform this job will be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery DataTables has the ability to use server side paging.  You can find detailed information here: [Server Side Paging Documentation](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)